# Loading question when not logged into Android app causes endless dialogs

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, android-app

When logged out of the app, visit a link from the web browser (or any app) that opens the Stack Exchange app. The app will go into a seemingly endless loop of "Failed to load. Please ensure you're connected to the Internet and try again" error dialogs. <kbd>Retry</kbd> arrives at the same failed dialog box. <kbd>Cancel</kbd> closes the app, but when I go back to the app not using the link (either by the app icon or the app switcher) the dialog is still there to continue the loop. I had to force close the app to break out of this loop.

<sub>using v0.1.48</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report! As of version 0.1.49 the app will push you over to the login screen when this happens.